# How to create a custom Error 419: Page Expired in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

Can you help me on how to customize the default **Page Expired** page in Laravel?

BTW, I'm new to Laravel.

Comment: You can create the following view: `resources/views/errors/419.blade.php` and customize it however you want. [Custom HTTP Error Pages](https://laravel.com/docs/master/errors#custom-http-error-pages).

Answer (score 16):

There's a way to override this view. All you need to do is create `419.blade.php` file inside the `resources/views/errors folder.`

If you need to find the Laravel's default `419.blade.php` file, you can publish vendor files:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-errors
```

Comment: If this was solution you were looking for, accept it as an answer, because it might help someone in the future.

Comment: just to add up, you can create custom error page on `resources/view/errors` folder. just name it based on the error code `404.blade.php`, `500.blade.php`, `401...`, `503...`, etc.

Comment: The best solution and @kapitan is so right. I tried it and everything is working